# How an interface can return a strict implementation of itself

Tags: java

Let's say that we have the following interface

```
public interface Animal {

    String getName();

    ArrayList<Animal> getPack();

}
```

And the following implementation of it

```
public class Wolf implements Animal {

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "wolf 1";
    }

    @Override
    public ArrayList<Animal> getPack() {
        return new ArrayList<>();
    }
}
```

Is there any way to have the following instead?

```
 @Override
 public ArrayList<Wolf> getPack() {
     return new ArrayList<>();
 }
```

Comment: No reason why not - but it's generally a Bad Idea TM for any element of an OO hierachy to know about elements lower down in the hierachy. `List` should not know about `ArrayList` or `LinkedList`. `Animal` should not know about `Wolf`.

Comment: The question is not about `Animal` knowing about `Wolf`. It's about defining the method with a generic self-reference in the return type so that it is always the same as the current implementing child class.

Comment: What Crusha mentioned is the point of the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
public interface Animal {

    String getName();

    ArrayList<? extends Animal> getPack();

}
```

Comment: That's the answer!

Answer (score 1):

You can "kind of" do this with a generic interface:

```
public interface Animal<T extends Animal<T>> {

    String getName();

    ArrayList<T> getPack();

}

public class Wolf implements Animal<Wolf> {
    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public ArrayList<Wolf> getPack() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

But the drawback of this is obviously that the responsibility of following rules is passed to the implementers. It is entirely possible to write a `Cat` class that implements `Animal<Wolf>`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I do not like this approach because of the drawback you already mentioned :S